Can I modify config values from appSettings in the app start up?
I have a .NET 8 application that uses the Options pattern for configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0
In my appSettings file I have the following section
"TokenOptions": {
    "BaseUri": "a-uri",
    "Username": "a-username",
    "Password": "a-password"
}

In my app, in ConfigureServices(), I do the following:
serviceCollection.Configure<TokenOptions>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenOptions)));
serviceCollection.AddTransient(resolver => resolver.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<TokenOptions>>().CurrentValue);


Then, through dependency injection, I can make TokenOptions available in any class and it will have the values from appSettings.
Now, I have certain scenarios where the section TokenOptions in the appSettings file may be missing or incomplete, for example, missing the BaseUri property.
Would it be possible in the start up of my app to validate if the entire section or one of its properties is missing and use a default hardcoded value before configuring the service?
I am not looking to update the actual appSettings file with the missing values, but just use the default values throughout my app if they are missing in the file. So, once my app has started and I need an instance of TokenOptions in a class, it should resolve to something like:
tokenOptions.BaseUri: "a-hardcoded-default-value";
tokenOptions.Username: "a-username"; //the value from appSettings
tokenOptions.Password: "a-password; //the value from appSettings


Let asume your config looks like this:
 "TokenOptions" : {
    "BaseUri" : "tmp",
    "UserName": "myUsareName",
    "Password": "MySecretPasswd!"
}

If you want validate this section you have to do:
builder.Services.AddOptions<TokenOptions>()
.Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenOptions)))
.ValidateDataAnnotations()
.ValidateOnStart();

var tokenOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenOptions)).Get<TokenOptions>();

TokenOptions.cs file:
public class TokenOptions
{
    [Required]
    public string? BaseUri { get; set; } 
    public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

In case of missing Required property you application will crash at start.
And if you want use some defeault values of properties just instead of string.Empty use for example: "localhost:5001"
public string BaseUri { get; set; } = "localhost:5001";

Check this for more options to validate:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-9.0

Thank you for taking the time to read and answer my question. Unfortunately, I cannot modify the class TokenOptions to add those default values as it comes from an external library.
